# How to align two divs in a table cell

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to vertical align two divs in a table-cell, using bootstrap 3 RC1. I have applied the vertical-align class but what am I missing? Bootply here: http://bootply.com/73625

HTML

```
<div class="content">

  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 child1">Child content</div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 child2">Child content</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.content{
position:absolute;
top:40px;
bottom:0px;
width:100%;
  border:4px solid green;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;

}

.child1{
  border:4px solid blue;
}

.child2{
  border:4px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely positioning an element negates `display: table-cell;` as it automatically makes an element block-level.

Comment: What position would work to achieve the 100% height I'm looking for?

Comment: Relative obviously wont work: http://bootply.com/73644

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.content{
  position:absolute;
  top:40px;
  bottom:0px;
  width:100%;
  border:4px solid green;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;

}

.child1{
  border:4px solid blue;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.child2{
  border:4px solid red;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: try to put this property in each child:
:::
margin:  % 0;
:::
where % is a percentage number that you want to put in the position.